# Windows(dev) to Linux(prod) Zend Framework migration errors

Tags: zend-framework, migration, case-sensitive, controllers

I'm getting the following error migrating my code across from my Windows dev machine to my linxu production machine. I'm aware there are always separator and case sensitivity issues (which I have fixed), however this one seems to be coming from the Framework itself.

My controllers are all following the convention (Uppercase first camel).

I'm using the bootstrap provided by Zend_App and this is all working (well with no errors) on my dev box.

Its parsing Plugins, however can't seem to get to controllers.

Any ideas would be great. :-)

---

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in /****mywebroot***/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:242 Stack trace: #0 //****mywebroot***/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /****mywebroot***/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(77): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 /****mywebroot***/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run() #4 {main} thrown in /****mywebroot***/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php on line 242
```

---

I'm hoping this is a basic error

Answer (score 2):

Triple check the case the name of files and directories your controllers are in.

This specific exception could also be caused by not having a default controller available.

Comment: Thanks again Lance.
It turns out you can have camel case controller names in windows (et UserGalleryController.php) but not in linux. When you try to access them from a plugin (you previous help :-)) it fails badly. I changed the name to lower case, and everything worked. Strange that it took out the error controller. Are controllers only initalised after plugins? What is the excution order? (->index.php->bootstrap.php->zend_app_instance->plugins->controller->view->layout ?) Thanks :-)

Comment: that should read above from (UserGallerController.php -> UsergalleryController (the ->setController function was failing even when you use hyphens in linux)